# Generate ramdisk during build and fill with content

Tags: linux, build, ramdisk

Is it, in some way, possible to create AND fill a ramdisk image with files without mounting the ramdisk?

I have a customized set of files for linux (so, just a bunch of files) which should be inside the filesystem. Now I want to have it executed during build which generates a ramdisk, formatting it with mkfs (needs no root) and then copy the files in some way into the ramdisk (but the way must not need root rights!) Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Possibly use `dd`?

Comment: I don't know. Thats the reason why I'm asking. How to get files (or at least a folder) into the ramdisk with dd?

Comment: What's the "ramdisk image"? It's an image or a ramdisk? Because image is a file, it can't be a ramdisk...

Comment: In the end its a image file which becomes a ramdisk during startup of my platform

Comment: @alabamajack If you have a saved image of the ramdisk I think you could just use `dd if=$PATH_TO_RAMDISKIMAGE of=$RAMDISKDEVICE`.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a loopback device.

Package to install: `libguestfs-tools`.

And it needs the Linux kernel image file (`/boot/vmlinuz-*-generic`) be readable by the user.

```
# Create mountpoint.
mkdir space
# Create image.
dd if=/dev/zero of=space.img bs=1024 count=255
# Format image.
/sbin/mkfs.ext4 space.img

# Mount image.
#
# There is a bug with it at least on Ubuntu:
# "The kernel is no longer readable by non-root users"
# https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/759725
#
# Fix: $ dpkg-statoverride --add --update root root 0644 /boot/vmlinuz-$(uname -r)
# Alternative fix is to chown the kernel image manually: chown a+r /boot/vmlinuz-*-generic
#
# Does uid/gid mapping, uses space.img as image, /dev/sda of the quest as partition, space/ as the mount point.
guestmount -o uid=$(id -u) -o gid=$(id -g) -o default_permissions -a space.img -m /dev/sda space

# do things

# Unmount.
guestunmount space
```

Answer (score 0):

`mount` is used for sharing a file system for user usage. That 'sharing' ( connection between file/thing containing the filesystem and user accessible directory and file structure) is done by a `module` in kernel (program running inside the kernel). That 'program' translates user request (ex. create file) to operations on the filesystem.
What we need is a filesystem program which runs in userspace and does not call `mount`. Userspace filesystems implementations are called [fuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) and i know there are fuse implementation of popular filesystems. 
Anyway, i am not aware of any popular program, that will for example create a file in a filesystem on a file without 'mounting' it to a directory. You may browse examples on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace), maybe you will find such program.
I would go with writing such program myself.
You may write your own filesystem or choose to use existing one and write a program to modify the content of a file (or ramdisk image, on linux it's a file) and then use this program to create and modify the content of this filesystem, without executing linux `mount` call.
For example you may use [fat_fs](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html) library, used in many embedded systems, implement fat_fs callbacks functions ex. disc_read() disc_write() to read and write from your file/ramdisc, and then call fat_fs functions to modify the content of the ramdisc/file. Such embedded libraries shouldn't do any calls to `mount` or any linux syscalls, as these calls are missing on embedded systems.
PS. On my university there are such classes, that students must write a simple filesystem program that opens a file and supports files creation, modification and deletion in the filesystem in this file.